# Emacs + magit - vertical blame

Tags: emacs, magit

I recently decided to switch from vim to spacemacs, which has already magit included. When working with Vim it is very easy to show :Gblame, and it shows vertical menu with commits, its author and side by side code (similar how to original git blame works).

I discovered magit-blame, but it shows diff in different way (commit, author and below code) which seems unnatural to me. Is it possible to change this view to be similar how fugitive works? I know that emacs is editor of near endless possibilities so it must be possible in some way.

I discovered also that I can use vc-annotate but it doesn't preserve syntax highlighting.

Comment: Good question, worth asking on the issue tracker in my opinion: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues Magit and git-gutter both use [overlays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html) but git-gutter puts its data on a left sided column. I would start my investigation here…

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's supported now (see tarsius' link)!

Run `magit-blame`, then `magit-blame-cycle-style` (or `magit-blame` again then `c`) to cycle to the vertical mode.

Comment: Any way to set it as default?

Comment: This still works as of 03/2021, but is deprecated. `magit-blame-addition` is the new name.

Answer (score 1):

Magit does not currently support this, but there are plans to support multiple display styles: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2937.

Comment: thank you for the commit https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/a80da3d66fab3b12b8044b97634a8319bbe32025 so you can update this answer ;)